# I cannot create a file in C++ using fstream

Tags: c++, file, fstream

This is my first question here on stack overflow, so have mercy if I screw up with anything (lol)
Coding language: C++
IDE: Code::blocks
Compiler: GNU GCC
OS: Windows

Let me clarify:
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main() {
   std::fstream fileObject;
   std::string line;
   fileObject.open("randomFile.txt");

   fileObject << "Random text\n kjshjdfgxhkjlwkdgxsdegysh";
   while (getline(fileObject, line)   ) {
       std::cout << line << "\n";
   }
   fileObject.close();
}
```

This does not make any errors, but when I check my project file, the file randomFile is not there, nor does any text appear on the console screen.
But, this code does work :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main() {
    std::ofstream fileObject;
    fileObject.open("randomFile.txt");
    fileObject << "Random text\n kjshjdfgxhkjlwkdgxsdegysh";
    fileObject.close();
}
```

It creates the file and inserts the specified text...
I also have a secondary problem: If I try to make an ifstream and ofstream object with the same name, it shows up as an error, yet I cannot figure out how to make it so that I can both write to a file and read from it using the same code...

Comment: Did you check if the file appears in the `Debug` folder (or wherever the `.exe` is created)?

Comment: How do you know there aren't any errors? There is no error checking. All sorts of bad smurf could be happening, and if you don't check, you won't know.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by terminating input...

Comment: @fartgeek That's most likely not the problem, you `close()` the file anyways.

Comment: I did check in the folder where the .exe is created, there is nothing there

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `fstream fileObject; fileObject.open(“randomfile.txt”);` to `fstream fileObject(“randomfile.txt”);`. And you don’t need to call `fileObject.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: Does the `.exe` run in any other directory? Check the debug settinga of your IDE please.

Comment: I am kind of confused. I am trying to ask another question, but it says that since "my question was not recieved well by the community", I cannot ask again for a few days: I have a few problems with that. What did I do wrong? Can someone please explain? What is the point of downvoting my post? The only thing you will be doing is discouraging me form asking more..

Comment: Gfaffagagavagafafafafafa

Comment: Sorry I am commenting for a badge lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the documentation, you can't program C++ by guess work. These options allow you to open a file for simultaneous reading and writing, but with the following caveats

```
// error if the file does not exist
std::fstream fileObject("randomFile.txt");
```

or (same thing)

```
// error if the file does not exist
std::fstream fileObject("randomFile.txt", 
    std::ios_base::in|std::ios_base::out);
```

or

```
// destroys contents if the file exists, but creates file if it does not
std::fstream fileObject("randomFile.txt", 
    std::ios_base::in|std::ios_base::out|std::ios_base::trunc);
```

If neither of these options is exactly what you want then you are going to have to check for the files existence before you open the file.

Reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. I didn't know you couldn't create a file with std::fstream...

Comment: @fartgeek - It's quite possible to create a file with `std::fstream`.   The point of this answer is that, by default, attempting to open a non-existent file will result in an error, not creating the file.    You opened the `fstream` in the default manner, so opening a non-existent file produces an error.    If you want to create a file using `fstream` it it is necessary to provide appropriate value of the second argument.